# How to best call catkin_add_gtest and add_rostest_gtest separately?

Tags: ros, unit-testing, catkin-tools

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to test ROS code at two different levels (calling `catkin_add_gtest` and `add_rostest_gtest` separately), and I haven't found documentation on exactly how to do what I'm hoping to do.

Essentially, I have `src/library.cpp` that I'd want to run `gtest` tests on through `test/test_library.cpp`. This should test low-level functionality - just the methods and functions defined in `library.cpp`, without any need of having a node running or publishing/subscribing.

I'd also like to run a full-fledged node-level test, running multiple nodes through `rostest` (defined in a `test/test_node.test` file), spun up through a `gtest` node defined in `test/test_node.cpp`.

The problem I'm facing is that if I run `catkin run_tests package_name`, this runs *both* the `catkin_add_gtest` and `add_rostest_gtest` targets. I'd like to use some command to run only one or the other, not both. How might I do that?

See example `CMakeLists.txt` below.

```
# CMakeLists.txt
...
add_library(library src/library.cpp )
target_link_libraries(library ${catkin_LIBRARIES})

if(CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING)

  if(TARGET run_library_test) # can I do this?
    find_package(catkin REQUIRED rostest)
    catkin_add_gtest(test_library test/test_library.cpp)
    target_link_libraries(test_library library ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
  endif() # run_library_test

  if(TARGET run_node_test) # can I do this?
    find_package(catkin REQUIRED rostest)
    add_rostest_gtest(test_node test/test_node.test test/test_node.cpp)
    target_link_libraries(test_node library ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
  endif() # run_node_test

endif() # CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/271167/how-to-best-call-catkin_add_gtest-and-add_rostest_gtest-separately?/) by [nckswt](https://answers.ros.org/users/3362/nckswt/) on ROS Answers with karma: 539 on 2017-09-19

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had this problem as well and this was my solution

For reference, I refer to unit tests as the library tests (ie: no ROS environment) and integration tests as tests done with rostest

Add in two options in the top of your CMake (or your root CMake)

```
option(BUILD_UNIT_TESTS "Build the unit tests" OFF)
option(BUILD_INTEGRATION_TESTS "Build the integration tests" OFF)
```

Write your tests block similar to your above example

```
if(CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING)
  if(BUILD_UNIT_TESTS)
    catkin_add_gtest(
      primary_controller_unit_tests
      test/unit_tests.cpp
    )
    if(TARGET primary_controller_unit_tests)
      target_link_libraries(
        primary_controller_unit_tests 
        ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
        ${PROJECT_NAME}
      )
    endif()
  endif(BUILD_UNIT_TESTS)

  if(BUILD_INTEGRATION_TESTS)
    add_rostest_gtest(
      primary_controller_integration_tests 
      test/integration_tests.test 
      test/integration_tests.cpp
    )
    if(TARGET primary_controller_integration_tests)
      target_link_libraries(
        primary_controller_integration_tests 
        ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
        ${PROJECT_NAME}
      )
    endif()
  endif(BUILD_INTEGRATION_TESTS)

endif(CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING)
```

Then when invoking catkin, use

```
catkin_make run_tests --cmake-args -DBUILD_UNIT_TESTS=OFF -DBUILD_INTEGRATION_TESTS=ON
```

I'm in the attempt of making a ROS template which will work with GitLab (this sort of functionality makes sense for a CI), if its of any use to anyone else see it here https://github.com/ALTinners/ros-gitlab-ci-example

---

Originally posted by [ALTinners](https://answers.ros.org/users/36898/altinners/) with karma: 26 on 2018-08-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2018-08-27**:
Using a custom CMake option like `BUILD_INTEGRATION_TESTS` which defaults to `OFF` will prevent you from running these tests on e.g. the ROS buildfarm (since it doesn't know about the option and won't enable it).

**Comment by [ALTinners](https://answers.ros.org/users/36898/altinners/) on 2018-08-28**:
That was on purpose though - that particular project was intended to be run as a Build/Unit/Integration/Acceptance procedure, with early exit if a stage failed. You'd modify the catkin/cmake command you use based on the level of testing you wanted to perform, and change CMake defaults if needed.